# Scaling images in-browser via CSS vs server-side PHP

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image, scaling

I'm building a Wordpress theme that will use imported posts from another site.
These posts have images that vary in size and aspect ratio.
There are predefined areas on the new theme where these image must fit, and fill the area, with centering and without letterboxing.
Without breaking the semantics of the img tag by using background images, I've put together a few techniques I've seen elsewhere to scale images and fit/center them to a panel, like this:

CSS:

```
.fillwidth { 
 width: 100%; 
 height: auto; 
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;              
 transform: translateY(-50%);       
}
.fillheight { 
 height: 100%; 
 width: auto; 
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}

div {
 border: 1px solid black;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
```

JS:

```
<script src="http://localhost/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script>
(function($){
 $('div').each(function() {
 var fillClass = ($(this).height() > $(this).width()) 
 ? 'fillheight'
 : 'fillwidth';
 $(this).find('img').addClass(fillClass);
 });
})(window.jQuery);
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div>
 <img src="test.jpg" />
</div>
```

So basically the JS determines the aspect ratio, the image is fit to the box and a transform centers it.

Now my question is, on a high traffic Wordpress site, would you recommend allowing the user's browser to do this resizing on the front end, or should the theme create multiple versions of uploaded images to fit the various panels on the site in advance? With modern browsers what is the impact of asking the browser to do the scaling and resizing of images?

Comment: if the browser does the re-sizing the client still has to transfer the whole file. if you do it server side, the file size will be much smaller

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to let the browser resize images, when coupled with a poor connection it can be noticeably slower to load pages, especially when `img` width and height attributes aren't specified. Are you able to declare new featured image sizes via `wp_add_image_size`?

Comment: There really isn't much issue when resizing images with JS. The real impact of images on a website is load time. If you have bigger images, your website is going to load slower than if you had smaller. Plus if you are on a shared host which limits bandwidth, pre-resizing would be better.

Comment: best solution for load time and server efficiency is to create the different sizes when the image is uploaded, you can then use js to load the appropriate size for the container / screen size.

Comment: OK great I guess I should use wp_add_image_size which would also help take care of the responsive version of the site, for new psots, and just write a script to preprocess all of the initial posts I'm importing to generate images at the right size?